# Execute server side code on ModalPopupExtender okcontrolid clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am using ASP.NET and C#. I want to popup this little screen, then when the OK button is clicked, I want to update the main screen based on the input to the popup. Sounds like it should be a regular thing. Is it possible, and if so, how?

```
    <cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" 
cancelcontrolid="btnCancel" okcontrolid="btnOkay" 
targetcontrolid="txtCosCodeExpCode" popupcontrolid="Panel1" 
popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" 
backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
    </cc1:modalpopupextender>

    <asp:panel id="Panel1" style="display: none" runat="server">
<div class="CostCentreExpenseCodePopup" style="background-color:White ; border-style :solid;">
            <div class="PopupHeader" id="PopupHeader">Select Cost Centre / Expense Code</div>
            <div class="PopupBody">
                <p>Cost Centre<asp:DropDownList 
                                            ID="ddlCostCentres1" 
                                            runat="server" 
                                            CssClass="SVSComboBox1" 
                                            AppendDataBoundItems ="True"
                                            AutoPostBack="True" 
                                            style = "width :152px;"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCostCentres1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Please select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList></p>

                <p>Expense Code <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpCode1" runat="server" CssClass="SVSComboBox1" style = "width :152px;"
                                            AppendDataBoundItems ="True" Enabled="False" Visible ="False">
                                            <asp:ListItem Text="Please select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList></p>
            </div>
            <div class="Controls">
                <input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />
                <input id="btnCancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `OkControlID` but use `ModalPopupExtender1.Hide()` on server-side. Then you're able to call your  update-code first.

You should also use server-buttons instead of `<input id="btnOkay" type="button" value="Done" />` and handle their click-event.

Answer (score 0):

First of all add the `asp:Button` as an Ok button and add click event in your aspx.cs page as mentioned below:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOkay" Text="OK" OnClick="btnOkay_Click"/>
```

**ASPX.cs**

```
protected void btnOkay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code to write on ok click event
}
```

And then remove `okcontrolid="btnOkay"` from your modal popup extender.