# modal popup extender button event using c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have written modalpopupextender and it is successfully displaying. My problem is after enter the text in modalpopup i will click on save button but it is not working, after clicking the button popup will close and data will not store in my database following are the aspx code

```
 <asp:Button ID="freeservice" runat="server" CssClass="hidden" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="mpe" PopupControlID="panel" TargetControlID="freeservice" OkControlID="savetxt"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="cancel"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none;">
        <asp:Button ID="cancel" runat="server" Text="X" CssClass="modalDialog" />
        <div class="Popup_header">
            Free service
        </div>
        <div class="modalbody">
            <h3>Do you want to get free text update on your mobile when IRS takes decision on your
            form?
            <br />
                If yes, please enter mobile number on which you want to get update:</h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile Number</td>
                    <td style="width: 1px">
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server" CssClass="divtxt"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revmobile" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true"
                             Display="None" ErrorMessage="Mobile number must be of 10 digits" ControlToValidate="txtmobile"
                             ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_revmobile" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right" 
                            TargetControlID="revmobile" HighlightCssClass="errorField"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftemobile" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtmobile" ValidChars="0123456789"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                    </td>
                    <td>(Not Mandatory)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <h3>Do you want to get Schedule 1 by fax for free?
            <br />
                If yes, please enter fax number where you want to receive your Schedule 1:
            </h3>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:24%">Fax Number</td>
                    <td style="width: 1px">
                       <asp:TextBox ID="txtfax" runat="server" CssClass="divtxt"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revfax" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfax" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Fax number must be of 10 digits"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="vce_revfax" runat="server" PopupPosition="Right" TargetControlID="revfax" HighlightCssClass="errorField"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                        <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftefax" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtfax" ValidChars="0123456789"></asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                    </td>
                    <td>(Not Mandatory)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: right; padding-top: 6px;">
           <asp:Button runat="server" ID="savetxt" OnClick="savetxt_Click" Text="Save" CssClass="btn" />
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
```

and my back end code is

```
 protected void savetxt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            Form2290.FreeServices objFreeService = new FreeServices();

            objFreeService.FormID = Convert.ToString(Session["FORM_KEY"]);
            objFreeService.Mobile = txtmobile.Text.Trim();
            objFreeService.Fax = txtfax.Text.Trim();

            BAL_F2290 objBAL = new BAL_F2290();
            objBAL.SaveFreeServices(objFreeService);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string a = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

please help me

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on the backend click event? If so, does it get hit?

Comment: This should give you the answer you are looking for - [Execute serverside code from modalpopup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139053/execute-server-side-code-on-modalpopupextender-okcontrolid-clicked)

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys i made mistake in modalpopupextender i have set **okcontrolID="savetxt"** should not be there. Just i removed and code successfully executed.  Thanks guys for helping me